# Nuxt Vuetify i18n config

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxt-i18n

I would like to set Vuetify i18n config based on global i18n config (using @nuxtjs/i18n), but can't get access in vuetify.config.js

nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    ],
    i18n: { ... }
}
```

vuetify.config.js

```
export default function ({ app }) {
  console.log(app) // app config has i18n
  console.log(app.i18n) // undefined
}
```